# What are some better approaches to this (greedy?) problem

Tags: algorithm, greedy

Let's say I have n boxes, where inside each box is some value `b[i]`. I can guarantee that an array of boxes is sorted such that `b[1] <= b[2] <= ... <= b[n]`. I can also guarantee that there is an element `b[i] = x` and I would like to find which box `x` is in. The catch is that opening each box `b[i]` has some cost `c[i]`.

The problem is how can I minimise the total cost in finding `x`? My intuitive approach is to do a binary search on the `b[i]`'s. This reduces the total number of operations (since I get that O(logn) comparisons) but I can't exactly see how this would minimise the total cost.

Clearly, just picking the cheapest box and continuing would not work since in the worst case I would open every box. Any ideas on how I could improve this or how I can prove that my approach is optimal/not optimal?

Comment: you need to provide more infor , for example sample input and output

Comment: A mix of both approaches might get you somewhere: at each step, select the cheapest box, but get rid of unwanted boxes in case of failure using the criteria of binary search. I'm not sure what ratio, if any, you can guarantee with that approach however. Where does this problem come from?

Comment: "just picking the cheapest box and continuing would not work since in the worst case I would open every box."  Greedy Algorithms are not optimal, they're cheap.  Quite often a Greedy Algorithm will give you the unique worst answer.

Comment: You should find inspiration if you study the [Knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use dynamic programming to find the optimal decision tree. Let `T(i, j)` be the worst-case cost of searching locations `i..j`. Then

```
T(i, j) = { 0,                                              if i > j;
          { min_{k=i}^j (c[k] + max(T(i, k-1), T(k+1, j))), otherwise.
```

Remember the best choice of `k` for each interval.

The running time is `O(n^3)`, reducible to `O(n^2)` using Knuth's trick for [optimal BST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_binary_search_tree).